# How to find rows matching a dict property if the column contains dict

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have to find rows matching `we = 2`

```
import pandas as pd

# Create mock dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [20, 30, {'ab':1, 'we':2, 'as':3}, 'String1'],
    [21, 31, {'ab':4, 'we':5, 'as':6}, 'String2'],
    [22, 32, {'ab':7, 'we':2, 'as':9}, 'String2'],
], columns=['Col A', 'Col B', 'Col C', 'Col D'])
```

How can I do this in this case because the `Col C` contains a `dict`

Answer (score 3):

We can use the [`str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html) accesssor to access the value in the `dict` then use normal comparison to test for the value. In this example, select `we` and [`eq(2)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html). The mask (`m`) can be used to filter the DataFrame to find matches:

```
m = df['Col C'].str['we'].eq(2)
filtered_df = df[m]
```

---

If going to assign to `filtered_df` use [`copy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) to avoid a later `SettingWithCopyWarning`:

```
filtered_df = df[m].copy()
```

---

Naturally this can be done in one line without a separate variable:

```
filtered_df = df[df['Col C'].str['we'].eq(2)].copy()
```

`filtered_df`:

```
   Col A  Col B                        Col C    Col D
0     20     30  {'ab': 1, 'we': 2, 'as': 3}  String1
2     22     32  {'ab': 7, 'we': 2, 'as': 9}  String2
```

Comment: What's the difference of quoting `df.columns` as the second parameter of `df.loc` as opposed to `:`  or don't quote second parameter altogether?   i.e.  why don't use `df.loc[m, :]` or just `df.loc[m]` instead ?

Comment: Hi Henry, I tested 4 varieties with `df[m]`, `df.loc[m]`, `df.loc[m, :]` and `df.loc[m, df.columns]` on also Pandas 1.3.0.  Only `df[m]` gets the `SettingWithCopyWarning`.  All the 3 varieties with `df.loc` didn't get any warning/error message.  Can you please point me to any documentation / article mentioning about this?  I've also referenced the [classic question in SO that many of us refer to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas) but still got no mentioning about this.  You can also consider sharing this point to that question.

Comment: Thanks Henry.  I'll also try the `_is_copy` test  probably tomorrow.  Will let you know the finding afterwards. Thanks!  :-)

Comment: @SeaBean apparently explicitly selecting columns is an edge case which does not correctly set `_is_copy`. I've corrected my answer to use `copy` which is the correct way to handle this case. [Issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/42703)

Comment: Hi Henry, I tested with `_is_copy` and `_is_view` but couldn't arrive at a concrete conclusion like you.  Yeah, using `copy`, though could be at a cost, is a sure shot that can avoid the warning.   Upvoted.